# Open source code for firebase analytics (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to know if the source code of firebase-analytics is open or not. I couldn't find it in [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk) repo or any where else.

I wanted to know the working and flow of the api's available in the firebase-analytics. It's just weird that all the codes are available except analytics.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2159) for the same in the firebase-android-sdk repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The source code for the Google Analytics portion of the Firebase Android SDKs is currently **not** open-sourced.

While we open-sourced most of our product SDKs by now, it has taken different amounts of time for different products. We hope to some day have all our SDKs open-sourced, but have no timeline for when this will be.